# Spring Boot will not start when using Spring Integration and JdbcMetadataStore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to use Spring Integration to read files via `SFTP` and to use multiple servers to only read each file once.  I have configured the `SFTP` reader within Spring Boot and it works with the in-memory metadata store.  When I configure the `JdbcMetadataStore` using Postgres, Spring boot will no longer start and there is no error message other than Tomcat is shutting down.  I am using Spring Boot with JPA and Spring WS

```
2018-10-22 11:16:06.098  INFO 6775 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-22 11:16:06.106  INFO 6775 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'metadataStore' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-22 11:16:06.114  INFO 6775 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'metadataStore': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata:name=metadataStore,type=JdbcMetadataStore]
2018-10-22 11:16:06.125  INFO 6775 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

I am using annotation based configuration

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(this.host);
    factory.setPort(this.port);
    factory.setUser(this.username);
    factory.setPassword(this.password);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpMessageSource(ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore) {
    final SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("/");
     messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore,
             "INT_"));
    //messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
    //        "streaming"));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
    return new StreamTransformer();
}

@Bean
public SftpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
    return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
}
```

Comment: That is a pretty common setup. Do you have any particular logging setup that prevents the error from being shown? Perhaps you should try the `--debug` to see if you can get some more info. PS: In Sprint Integration errors/exceptions are sent by default to the error channel, perhaps are you disabling it?

Comment: Nothing obvious from your code and everything really looks typical. Try to turn on DEBUG logging to get more info from logs.

Comment: I had full tracing on and no indication of where the error was other than it was dying after adding it to JMX

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it failed when trying to load the metadatastore to JMX.  I then disabled JMX in Spring Boot and it fixed the issue.  Not sure why it was failing to add the bean to JMX but disabling JMX in the spring boot property(yml) file fixed the issue.

spring:
  jmx:
    enabled: false